# Unable to start the Virtual Device error genymotion

Tags: java, android, genymotion

I have successfully downloaded and installed Genymotion and Virtualbox as well as a Virtual Device Image but I am unable to start my virtual device.
I get an error message stating

> unable to set openGL hardware acceleration for the virtual device

can everybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the virtual device's memory to 512mb did it for me (before it was set to 1024mb)

Comment: I caused because of graphic card. I installed it completely and it works. thank you